# startVoiceRecognition security exception

Tags: android

I'm using the method `startVoiceRecognition` of class `BluetoothHeadset.` I can see from android vitals reports, a recurring security exception on Android Pie calling this method. I can't test it on emulator and I don't have a Pie phone to test. From documentation it seems only BLUETOOTH permission is needed and my apps has already that permission. Can someone help me to understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to request the permission RECORD_AUDIO, add it on your AndroidManifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Read official [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting) first. After Android 6.0 (API level 23) you should invoked Runtime Permission

```
// Here, thisActivity is the current activity
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
        Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

    // Permission is not granted
    // Should we show an explanation?
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(thisActivity,
            Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)) {
        // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
        // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
        // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.
    } else {
        // No explanation needed; request the permission
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);

        // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an
        // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
        // result of the request.
    }
} else {
    // Permission has already been granted
}
```

Comment: bluetooth permission is not dangerous, so I don't know what you are talking about.